# Detecting window events in the SDL2 C# wrapper

Tags: c#, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using the [SDL2 C# wrapper](https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS) through FNA and I need to be able to detect when the window resizes, min/maximizes, etc. From what I've found it seems I should use the `SDL_EventFilter` delegate and `SDL_WindowEventID` enum. I've tried attaching such an event using `SDL_AddEventWatch` and `SDL_SetEventFilter` methods, but I'm not getting any events related to window management.

How do I use the SDL window events in the C# wrapper correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event polling loop add a case for `SDL_WINDOWEVENT`:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(out sdlEvent) == 1) {
     switch(sdlEvent.type) {
         case SDL_EventType.SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
             HandleWindowEvent(sdlEvent.window);
             break;

         // other events here ...
     }

     Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

And then you could have a method handling those events:

```
HandleWindowEvents(SDL_WindowEvent wEvent) {
    switch(wEvent.windowEvent) {
        case SDL_WindowEventID.SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
            Console.WriteLine($"Window resized: {wEvent.data1}x{wEvent.data2}");
            break;

        // more window events here ...
    }
}
```

> All window events are outlined in [the Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID).

Comment: Would you mind adding how to set up a event polling loop for the SDL wrapper? My attempts were using `SDL_SetEventFilter` and I can't get your example to work with that.

Comment: You still get the event passed in your filter method. Just do a switch on the event type like in my answer. Why exactly do you need to do that with the filter? Do you want to discard certain events?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't getting it to catch any of the events, so I assumed I was doing something wrong. I looked around in the FNA source and it turns out that FNA is already polling all the events, no wonder I'm not getting any of them! I couldn't find any way to access these events, I added a custom event to the FNA `Game` class for custom handling of the events. I guess I'll submit an issue and see if this is something to change in FNA. Thanks for the help!